# Is it possible to make Task Groups parameter values settable at release time?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-task-groups

I have a task group with multiple parameters and it's being used in my release pipeline.
Is it possible to make those parameters settable at release time?

For example

In my task group, I have these parameters

- Username = user123
- Password = password123

And that task group is being used as the task of my release pipeline
When I'm creating a release I want to make the Username and Password parameters to be settable before triggering the Create(release) button.

I tried to create a variable GetUsername with value $(Username) in the Variable tab and make it settable at release time but when creating a release the return value of $(Username) is not the user123 instead it's $(Username)

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set variable at trigering release. Simply there is no option for that.

[image]

But to have your pipeline working correctly with variables and task group (as with other regular task) you ust ensure that you have variables set in `Variables` tab (or dynamically during pipeline)

[image]

[image]